# Which if statement requires less computation?

Tags: math, optimization, complexity, conditions

I have

```
if (!b && c || a && c)
  //do action a
else 
  //...
```

Due to some internal relationship between a, b, and c. `!b && c || a && c` **is proved to be equivalent to** `(! a && b) || c`.

I just wonder will `(! a && b) || c` be simpler than `!b && c || a && c`? Can you prove it? Assume the chances of a,b,c to be True or False is equal.

I'm **not asking which style is better**. **I'm asking which statement has lower computational complexity**. Just like asking quick sort and Bubble Sort, which has lower computational complexity. You will not answer it depends, it is related to compiler and hardware because some hardware have special instruction for Bubble Sort. I hope to hear nlog(n) and n^2.

Comment: do you mean ((!b && c) || (a && c)) or (((!b && c) || a) && c)

Comment: This isn't something that will be provable in general. It will depend on the data type used (which you haven't specified), how the code interacts with your optimizer, the actual values and how they interact with your branch-prediction hardware etc. If you're interested, benchmark it. If you're very interested, benchmark it and examine the compiler output (assembler, bytecode or whatever it may be).

Comment: @PieterB I mean  ((!b && c) || (a && c)) . OR has less priority than AND.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, my application of [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) gives `!((!a && b) || c)`. I'm only focusing on the boolean aspect, not the short-circuit peculiarity.

Comment: @Useless You are right. The actual performance is affected by optimizer and hardware, etc. But can we study it mathematically and get some hint?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Style for control flow with validation checks](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148849/style-for-control-flow-with-validation-checks)

Comment: As boolean operations are among the least expensive instructions to execute and "if"s are one of the areas that hardware optimization concentrates on (speculative execution, instruction re-ordering etc.) then I would be surprised if you could measure any difference between the two versions.

Comment: @LoveRight - no, you can't prove it in any useful way, because there are too many unknowns. You could _maybe_ prove it given known compiler (and version), types, values and hardware. You haven't given us any of those, though, so the answer is: it's impossible to tell _a priori_ which will be faster, and there's nothing to prove.

Comment: @Useless Computer is a turning machine. All operations can trace back to basic turning operations. The feasibility of turning machine was proven long ago, by mathematics. But now you tell me it is impossible to tell computational complexity of the two statements.

Comment: So you want to know which version _would require fewest steps if implemented on a Turing machine_? This is a fixed number of operations, so algorithmic complexity isn't relevant, and the number of Turing steps isn't necessarily a good predictor of performance on any real system.

Comment: Yes, it is what I want to know. We may assign a,b,c with True or False, and see generally which version stops with fewer steps. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: The fewer operations you need to do, the less computationally complex it is. This is obvious. Mathematical proofs and Big O notation don't really make sense here, because the time taken averages out as a constant factor, so both will be of O(n)

Comment: I think this was a great question that generated some thought and lots of discussion. Not sure why its so minus

Answer (score 8, accepted):

a good optimizer will make any difference here moot

you can think in how the short circuit works:

with `if ((!b && c) || (a && c))` you get

```
if(b)goto OR2;
if(c)goto then_lbl;
OR2:
if(!a)goto else_lbl;
if(!c)goto else_lbl;
then_lbl://...
```

while with `if((! a && b) || c)` (the actual equivalent) you get

```
if(a) goto OR2;
if(b) goto then_lbl;
OR2:
if(!c) goto else_lbl;
then_lbl://..
```

so there is no real difference (you always go through 2 or 3 branches)

But I'll repeat my point: this kind of micro optimization is utterly **useless** to worry about unless it is part of a **provable** bottleneck and most times the problem *isn't* a malformed if statement

here you'll find that readability trumps speed

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's

```
(! a && b)
```

rather than

```
!(a && b)
```

?

If not, the brackets are unnecessary and just lead to confusion.

Either way, generally the less operations you have the better for the computer, and in both AND or OR conditions it's better to put the "simplest" first, your most effective way of writing this for the computer (not necessarily the reader) would be:

```
c || b && ! a
```

This is assuming C-style operator precedence for the logical operators.

Comment: I'm sure it's `(! a && b) || c`. The brackets are unnecessary. Sorry for confusing.

Answer (score 2):

The two statements have **the same** computational complexity. Both execute in constant time (in complexity terms), which can be written O(1). Since the number of input states is finite (8), it could hardly be otherwise.

If `a`, `b` and `c` are general expressions rather than variable, `!b && c || a && c` may cause `c` to be evaluated twice. If `c` is not idempotent (i.e. if running `c` a second time doesn't necessarily do what it did the first time), all bets are off. The two expressions you propose also don't execute `a`, `b` and `c` in the same order in all cases, so if their running time depends on the order in which they are called, again, all bets are off.

If what you're wondering is not, in fact, the computational complexity (which deals with [asymptotic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis) measures of amounts of computation) but exact the number of computation steps, then the answer is that there is no general answer. The exact number of computation steps depends on which model of computation you choose. For asymptotic analysis, the choice of model is mostly irrelevant: any reasonable model gives the same result (or sometimes there are a few reasonable choices of model, and you need to say which one you're using). If you want a finer analysis, you have to provide a detailed model.

It is completely useless to refine the analysis in this case because the practical difference is going to hinge on a lot of factors that cannot readily be predicted, including:

- what machine code the compiler generates (which depends on the compiler, the compiler version, the optimization settings, the target CPU, and the surrounding code);
- the exact model of CPU (since this will be affected by the amount of prefetching, the branch prediction, the instruction and data pipelines depth, etc.);
- what other code executed before (since this influences the state of the pipelines, the cache, the branch predictor, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Well cant really answer this because

```
if (!b && c || a && c)
```

is not equal to

```
if ((! a && b) || c)
```

The truth tables for each are below, abc output:

```
000 0
001 1
010 0
011 0
100 0
101 1
110 0
111 1
```

this doesnt match the above

```
000 0
001 1
010 1
011 1
100 0
101 1
110 0
111 1
```

test program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned int a,b,c;


int main ( void )
{
    for(a=0;a<2;a++)
    for(b=0;b<2;b++)
    for(c=0;c<2;c++)
    {
        printf("%u%u%u ",a,b,c);
        if (!b && c || a && c)
        {
            printf("1\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("0\n");
        }
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(a=0;a<2;a++)
    for(b=0;b<2;b++)
    for(c=0;c<2;c++)
    {
        printf("%u%u%u ",a,b,c);
        if ((! a && b) || c)
        {
            printf("1\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("0\n");
        }
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Please add more parenthesis to improve the order of operations, and/or post an equivalent equation, then we can talk about how they differ in complexity.

This is equivalent

```
    if (c && (!(!a && b)))
```

note clang's opinion on this syntax:

```
fun.c:5:12: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
    if (!b && c || a && c) return(1);
        ~~~^~~~ ~~
fun.c:5:12: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence this
      warning
    if (!b && c || a && c) return(1);
           ^
        (      )
fun.c:5:22: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
    if (!b && c || a && c) return(1);
                ~~ ~~^~~~
fun.c:5:22: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence this
      warning
    if (!b && c || a && c) return(1);
                     ^
                   (     )
```

Using arm as a test target, the answer is not going to be deterministic BTW, it is compiler and target and system dependent on which is faster, less computation, etc.  Looks on the surface with an arm and its instruction set features the first solution with gcc is clean and deterministic (no branches).

This will of course change with each compiler and target and also with whatever code surrounds that if statement. (note the version of gcc and clang/llvm can/will create different results).

```
unsigned int bool1 ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b, unsigned int c )
{
    if (!b && c || a && c) return(1);
    return(0);
}

unsigned int bool2 ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b, unsigned int c )
{
    if (c && (!(!a && b))) return(1);
    return(0);
}

//gcc

//00000000 <bool1>:
   //0: e2900000    adds    r0, r0, #0
   //4: 13a00001    movne   r0, #1
   //8: e3510000    cmp r1, #0
   //c: 03800001    orreq   r0, r0, #1
  //10: e3520000    cmp r2, #0
  //14: 03a00000    moveq   r0, #0
  //18: 12000001    andne   r0, r0, #1
  //1c: e12fff1e    bx  lr

//00000020 <bool2>:
  //20: e3520000    cmp r2, #0
  //24: 0a000005    beq 40 <bool2+0x20>
  //28: e2711001    rsbs    r1, r1, #1
  //2c: 33a01000    movcc   r1, #0
  //30: e3500000    cmp r0, #0
  //34: 01a00001    moveq   r0, r1
  //38: 13810001    orrne   r0, r1, #1
  //3c: e12fff1e    bx  lr
  //40: e1a00002    mov r0, r2
  //44: e12fff1e    bx  lr

//clang

//bool1:                                  @ @bool1
    //cmp   r1, #0
    //bne   .LBB0_2
    //cmp   r2, #0
    //movne r0, #1
    //movne pc, lr
//.LBB0_2:                                @ %lor.lhs.false
    //cmp   r2, #0
    //movne r2, #1
    //cmp   r0, #0
    //movne r0, #1
    //and   r0, r0, r2
    //mov   pc, lr

//bool2:                                  @ @bool2
    //mov   r3, r0
    //cmp   r2, #0
    //beq   .LBB1_2
    //mov   r0, #1
    //cmp   r3, #0
    //movne pc, lr
    //cmp   r1, #0
    //movne r0, #0
    //b .LBB1_3
//.LBB1_2:                                @ %if.end
    //mov   r0, #0
//.LBB1_3:                                @ %return
    //mov   pc, lr
```

Comment: Due to some internal relationship between a, b, and c. !b && c || a && c is proved to be equivalent to (! a && b) || c. I mean a,b,c have certain relationship, which makes the two statement equivalent. I'm sure. It is given.

Comment: Due to some internal relationship between a, b, and c, which I emphsized many times, I will not have the combinatios of 010 and 011. Thus the two truth tables are equivalent.